# Adding class based on checkbox selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to simply create code that checks whether an checkbox input has been checked. I have tried both `prop` and `is(':checked')`. I don't understand why my class is not adding.

Does anyone see what is wrong?

```js
if($('#checkText').is(':checked')) {
  $('#notiPhone').addClass('active');
  console.log('Text box should be showing');
 }
 else {
  $('#notiPhone').removeClass('active');
  console.log('Text box should NOT be showing');
 }
```

```css
#notiEmail, #notiPhone {
 display: none;
 transition: all .4s ease;
}
#notiEmail.active, #notiPhone.active {
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
 <input type="text" name="notiName" placeholder="Name">
 <p>What type of notifications would you like to receive?</p>
 <label>Text Notifications</label>
 <input type="checkbox" name="checkText" id="checkText" value="text">
 <label>Email Notifications</label>
 <input type="checkbox" name="checkEmail" id="checkEmail" value="email">
 <input type="email" name="notiEmail" id="notiEmail" placeholder="Email*">
 <input type="tel" name="notiPhone" id="notiPhone" placeholder="Phone*">
</form>
```

Comment: Because you are checking if it is checked when document is loaded not when it is changed. Use `$('#notiPhone').change(function() { ...})`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FYI you can do this with just CSS (no JS required):

```css
#notiEmail, #notiPhone {
  display: none;
}

#checkText:checked~#notiPhone {
  display: block;
}

#checkEmail:checked~#notiEmail {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" name="notiName" placeholder="Name">
  <p>What type of notifications would you like to receive?</p>
  <label>Text Notifications</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkText" id="checkText" value="text">
  <label>Email Notifications</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkEmail" id="checkEmail" value="email">
  <input type="email" name="notiEmail" id="notiEmail" placeholder="Email*">
  <input type="tel" name="notiPhone" id="notiPhone" placeholder="Phone*">
</form>
```

**UPDATE**

> Is there anyway to hide the sibling input and uncheck the check box so that only one input would show?

Use radio buttons instead:

```css
#notiEmail, #notiPhone {
  display: none;
}

#checkText:checked~#notiPhone {
  display: block;
}

#checkEmail:checked~#notiEmail {
  display: block;
}

/* 
  Make radio buttons look like checkboxes.
  (Eurgh. Not recommended.)
*/
input[type="radio"] {
  -webkit-appearance: checkbox; 
  -moz-appearance: checkbox;    
  -ms-appearance: checkbox; 
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" name="notiName" placeholder="Name">
  <p>What type of notifications would you like to receive?</p>
  <label for="checkNone">No notifications</label>
  <input type="radio" name="notifymethod" id="checkNone" checked="checked" value="none">
  <label for="checkText">Text Notifications</label>
  <input type="radio" name="notifymethod" id="checkText" value="text">
  <label for="checkEmail">Email Notifications</label>
  <input type="radio" name="notifymethod" id="checkEmail" value="email">
  <input type="email" name="notiEmail" id="notiEmail" placeholder="Email*">
  <input type="tel" name="notiPhone" id="notiPhone" placeholder="Phone*">
</form>
```

Comment: Nice. I didn't know there was a way to do this in CSS, Thanks!

Comment: Is there anyway to hide the sibling input and uncheck the check box so that only one input would show?

Comment: @Paul You could simply user radio buttons instead of checkboxes. See update.

Comment: Thanks. I need the checkboxes for this specific case though

Comment: @Paul Are you sure it has to be checkboxes. That's bad from a UX perspective since checkboxes are for selecting multiple options but here you're wanting the customer to pick only one of the options (not both). This is exactly what a radio button is for.

Comment: My example is slimmed down for example purposes. The user will be able to select multiple items from various sections.

Comment: @Paul Then perhaps you should have different groups of radio buttons. Its good practice to have your form work without any JS dependency. So think about how you would limit the user to particular options or combinations. I imagine that you would have a set of radio buttons for each various section.

Comment: FYI you can make radio buttons look like checkboxes but I wouldn't recommend it. (see updated css)

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You are showing/not showing your text box only at the beggining of your javascript, but you do not listen to the changes in the checkbox. You can correct this by adding

```
$('#checkText').change(function() {
...
})
```

Like this :

```js
$('#checkText').change(function() {
if($('#checkText').is(':checked')) {
  $('#notiPhone').addClass('active');
  console.log('Text box should be showing');
 }
 else {
  $('#notiPhone').removeClass('active');
  console.log('Text box should NOT be showing');
 }
});
```

```css
#notiEmail, #notiPhone {
 display: none;
 transition: all .4s ease;
}
#notiEmail.active, #notiPhone.active {
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
 <input type="text" name="notiName" placeholder="Name">
 <p>What type of notifications would you like to receive?</p>
 <label>Text Notifications</label>
 <input type="checkbox" name="checkText" id="checkText" value="text">
 <label>Email Notifications</label>
 <input type="checkbox" name="checkEmail" id="checkEmail" value="email">
 <input type="email" name="notiEmail" id="notiEmail" placeholder="Email*">
 <input type="tel" name="notiPhone" id="notiPhone" placeholder="Phone*">
</form>
```

Comment: inside of the `change` event there's no need to search for the checkbox on the DOM again, you can validate if it was checked or not with `this.checked` , `this` will be the reference to the checkbox element on the DOM

Answer (score 0):

you should listen to the change event of the checkbox

```
$('#checkText').change( () => {

  if($('#checkText').is(':checked')) {
    $('#notiPhone').addClass('active');
    console.log('Text box should be showing');
  } else {
   $('#notiPhone').removeClass('active');
   console.log('Text box should NOT be showing');
  }

});
```